# Ethics of Spinoza - Question about Translation

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, sentence-translation, spinoza, ethica

Spinoza, Ethics, De Dei, Propositio 15, Scholium:

> Si igitur ipsi ex suo hoc absurdo concludere tamen  volunt substantiam extensam debere esse finitam, **nihil aliud hercle faciunt quam si quis** ex eo quod finxit  circulum quadrati proprietates habere, concludit circulum non habere centrum ex quo omnes ad circumferentiam ductæ lineae sunt aequales

I understand the meaning of the sentence but I can not realize the literal meaning of the bolded part because of ***faciunt*** and ***si***.

In short Spinoza already explains that some authors conclude from an absurd proposition (A) that the extended substance must only be finite. He demonstrates absurdity of A and hence he deduced that the finiteness of the extended substance is not necessary. Here he says that if those authors persist in believing in A and conclude from it that the extended substance must be finite, they are like one who supposed a circle to have the properties of a square, and then concludes from this that the distance of the points on circumference from the centre of the circle is not equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literally, '...they do nothing different than if someone... (makes the other conclusion about a circle)'

Or, to translate a bit more loosely, '...what they do is no different than what some other person does if he/she... (makes the other conclusion)'

Or '...they act no differently than if some other person... (makes the other conclusion)'

The adjective *alius/alia/aliud* can be treated as a comparative, and *quam* can introduce the second term in the comparison. That second term can be either a single word or phrase, or (as here) a whole clause.